# Format for POST Request in iOS

Tags: ios, json, post

I am able to get the JSON Response in iOS code through POST Request only when the parameters are empty. Response from Server is { Token = "" }

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
```

But when I add any parameters like shown below, I get 400 status code as response.

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=aps@test.com&deviceCode=bhj234&pwd=1234"];
```

The interesting thing is the same parameters work in REST Client perfectly and gets a response. And also works in Android code too. In android a JSON object is created then these key value pairs are added to the JSON object

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("userName", "apple@test.com");
jsonObj.put("deviceCode", "Dev455");
jsonObj.put("pwd", "225");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

and request and then receives the correct response.

Can anyone suggest me the equivalent code for iOS for the above Android code?
My present code is

```
NSMutableString *URL=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://***.***.**.***/Serv.svc/Login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=aps@test.com&deviceCode=bhj234&pwd=1234"];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSLog(@"post:%@",postData);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSLog(@"post:%@",[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: if u given the url I show the full answer for u

Comment: I'm not sure about this line: [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

Comment: @anbu.karthik URL is hidden for privacy.

Comment: @user2260054 I even tried it with application/json alone. And I have tried all possible ways for headers still the response is 400

Answer (score 0):

In case if everything else doesn't work, try to pass parameters in url:

```
    NSString *URL=[[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://***.***.**.***/Serv.svc/Login?userName=aps@test.com&deviceCode=bhj234&pwd=1234"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    NSLog(@"post:%@",URL);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Once it worked for me, however this of course doesn't answer what is the problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

User [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and improt the following in your class

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
```

> Use the following code to for Post request:

```
- (void)sendPOSTRequest {
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userName",@"deviceCode",@"pwd",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple@test.com",@"Dev455",@"225", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
[manager POST:@"yourURL" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSError * error = nil;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation responseData] options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setValue:@"aps@test.com" forKey:@"userName"];
[dict setValue:@"vikkj107" forKey:@"deviceCode"];
[dict setValue:@"1234" forKey:@"pwd"];


NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

NSMutableString *URL=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://***.***.**.***/Serv/Register"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *resultStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Can I please know the explanation for why was the down vote for above answer I posted? Bcoz I want rectify it before handing it to the client. And my response comes fine in this code.